# Vs Blend + Windows 8: how can I set system notification theme's style for my elements in the app?

Tags: xaml, blend

I need to set styles for buttons in my application similar styles for button in notification windows (for windows 8)
Great thanks for any information

Answer (score 0):

The window that is used by `MessageBox` is not exposed, and it's not inheriting the styles from the application (and rightly so).

The solution, usually, is to roll your own message box service that will use a window that you designed. Since it'll inherit from `Window` it'll use the styles from the application.

Comment: Please don't roll your own `MessageBox`. You'll just get it wrong and frustrate your users.

Comment: I tried use <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/> </Style> for my buttons but couldn't find right style. Is it a wrong way?

Comment: @CodyGray - I agree, rolling your own is not fun and you need to know how to simulate all the functionality of the Massage Box. But, if the designer can convince the PO that it's a must to have styled messages - I don't know another way to have styled message boxes in an application.